# How to use culture code name as subsite in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to use culture code name ("fr, lb, ru") as subsite in sitecore www.mydomain.com/ru, Site is working fine but content is not being shown

giving this message

"The current item does not have a version in "Russian : русский".
To create a version, click Add a New Version or click Add on the Versions tab."

my site configuration is

Please help me to use "ru, fr, sa, lb" as subsite names in sitecore.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show what are site configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want Sitecore to interpret the first part of the URL as language code and to instead resolve to an item in the content tree then you can change the following:

```xml
<setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" />
```

This prevents the StripLanguage processor in preprocessRequest pipeline from removing the language from the path and rewriting the URL.

You should also update the settings of the LinkProvider and set `languageEmbedding=false`.

You can read more details in this blog post: 
[Prevent the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS from Interpreting URL Path Prefixes as Language Names](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/prevent-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms-from-interpreting-url-path-prefixes-as-language-names)

Comment: Thanks buddy, it worked, what if want to use multiple languages in microsites, what would be the solution?
for example

www.mydomain.com/ru/home -> english
www.mydomain.com/ru/home -> russian

Comment: Both those URLs are the same, how do you distinguish between different languages? It is possible, I've done something similar before, best to raise it as a separate question with the specific requirements you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the LanguageResolver pipeline handler expects the language part of the URL to correspond to the full language name. So in your case it would expect `www.mydomain.com/ru-RU`. It is quite simple to create a custom LanguageResolver inheriting from the Sitecore one which is in Sitecore.Kernel.dll. 
The config element is

```xml
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

which you would need to patch to reference your new class. Your new class would override the `Process` method.